# Running a program on Notepad++

Tags: netbeans, notepad++

How can I run a program with  Notepad++ if I have Netbeans installed? I don't want to use an IDE so I can get better at programming.

Comment: Compile your source code using a suitable compiler, and run the resulting executable from a command prompt.  That's all Netbeans does, behind the scenes.

Comment: I'd argue that using an IDE will make you better at programming. Whenever you write code at a job you will be using an IDE so you might as well practice with similar tools that you will actually be using. Knowing how to efficiently use your IDE is a large part of being a good programmer.

Comment: Yes, I know but in exams, we don't use an IDE. We have to write on paper.

Comment: It's very, very debatable that using a text editor will provide any meaningful improvement in your programming ability over a more full-fledged IDE like NetBeans. So folks may feel that the code completion that can be offered by such things handicaps a fledgling programmer, but I feel that theory is bunk. Being a good programmer has nothing to do with memorizing APIs; it has everything to do with learning about problem solving and thinking about problems in a way that allows them to be solved with code.

Comment: which language are u making the programs in?

Comment: @AdamCrossland I think there's ample evidence to the contrary, e.g. CTRL+clicking to a method definition can prevent one from learning how objects interact.

Comment: Then I think you need to use the Java Compiler on the Command Line Interface (CLI). And then run it in CLI too...

I think for compiling you use: javac
and for running you use: java


see their help to know how to compile and run programs... :D

Comment: @paislee, I'm sorry but I just don't get the connection.

Comment: If Notepad++ can't run an external executable then I would suggest finding an alternative text editor. There are plenty of programmer's editors that can do this. I also agree with you in that I too think you wil become a better programmer if you can program outside of the IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notepad++ can't run programs. You'll need to find a compiler, interpreter, and/or runtime for the language in which your program is written.